# Prevent brief tab title of npm package name when loading with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

With Vue 3 and `vue-router`, I'm having trouble having accurate tab titles - upon first load, the name of the NPM package, `client`, is displayed for several hundred milliseconds.

Currently, tab titles are assigned in the `meta` option of routes in `router.js`, which is imported to the `main.js` entrypoint of the Vue app.

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: Landing,
      name: "home",
      meta: {
        title: "My Cool Title",
      },
    },
```

A watcher is set up in `App.vue` for setting the document title as so:

```
  watch: {
    "$route" (to) {
      document.title = to.meta.title || "Fallback";
    }
  }
```

However, upon initially loading the app, the name `"client"` is used as a title for almost a second, as it is the name of the project in `package.json`. Also, switching between routes (which doesn't trigger a reload) also holds the previous title for half a second or so.

How can I get the document title to be set to the desired meta tag *before* it is even loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with vue 3 I recommend to use this plugin called [vueuse/head](https://github.com/vueuse/head) :

Installation :

```
pm i @vueuse/head -S
```

Usage :

`main.js`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createHead } from '@vueuse/head'

const app = createApp()
const head = createHead()

app.use(head)

app.mount('#app')
```

`App.vue` :

```
<script>
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue'
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head'
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
   const route=useRoute()

    useHead({

      title: computed(() => route.meta.title),
     
    })
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: This works when switching between router views, but does not address the initial "client" show-up.

Comment: Still not functioning in the expected way. However, I've noticed that other websites typically show the name of the site before loading the full document title, so I'll use the less programmatic approach and simply hardcode a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following:

- Set a `immediate: true` for your watcher

```
watch: {
    "$route": {
      handler(to) {
       document.title = to.meta.title || "Fallback";
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
}
```

- Scrap watcher approach and set [global before guard](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) in main.js

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 document.title = to.meta.title
 next()
})
```